# How do I get scons to clone a git repository, and checkout a specified tag?

Tags: scons

I'm attempting to get **scons** to clone a git repository and to checkout a particular tag. I'm trying the following, but it never runs the `git checkout` command:

```
env = Environment()

env.Command("deps/lager/.git", None,
    "git clone -q git://github.com/basho/lager.git deps/lager")
env.Command(None, "deps/lager/.git",
    "cd deps/lager && git checkout -q 2.0.3")
```

I want to avoid cloning the repository every time I run `scons`, but I *do* want the specified tag checked out each time.

If I try the following:

```
env.AlwaysBuild(
    env.Command(None, "deps/lager/.git",
        "cd deps/lager && git checkout -q 2.0.3"))
```

...then it tries to run this first, before the repository is cloned.

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to work, but I don't know whether it's a good idea:

```
x = env.Command("deps/lager/.git", None,
    "git clone -q git://github.com/basho/lager.git deps/lager")
env.Command("deps/lager/.git#2.0.3", x,
    "cd deps/lager && git checkout -q 2.0.3")
```

Comment: A bit late, but about the "good idea" thing, I wonder if you should not manage this wit git submodules directly.